# programmatically focused link gets focused, but the style doesn't apply

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to focus a link programmatically. The following stackblitz shows the behavior:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9jocb8?file=src%2Fmain.ts,package.json

if you click on the button, the link should get focused. It actually gets the focus, but you cannot see it.
If you change the code, so the button focuses the nearby input field, everything works well.
One more thing I noticed is that when the focus is actually on the button when you click it, the focus on the link works perfectly fine.

Steps to reproduce:

- Open the link
- click on the button

Expected Behavior: Link is visually focused

Actual Behavior: Link is focused, but you cannot see it (tab back and forth shows the actual focus)

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

I simplified the example a bit, in my real app I want to focus a link inside an innerHtml div in the onInit hook (or any other angular hook - none worked for me). So I just render a component with a div that gets filled by a server response. The server response includes a link and I want to focus the first link when the component is initialized.

The relevant code looks like this:

```
@Input
message: string;

ngOnInit(): void {
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.querySelector<HTMLLinkElement>('.some-container a')?.focus();
  }, 0);
}
```

the html:

```
<div #someId [innerHTML]="message" aria-live="assertive" class="some-container" role="alert">
</div>
```

the component only gets rendered, when message is filled (`*ngIf="message"` when using the component in its parent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links focus might be difficult to see, your code works great, all we need to do, is add some CSS so that the focus is visible to the end user!

style

```
a:focus {border: 2px solid black;  }
```

full code

```
import 'zone.js';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview" tabIndex='1'>
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
    <br>
    <input/>
    <button (click)="clickMe()">click</button>
  `,
  styles: [
    `a:focus {border: 2px solid black;  }`
  ]
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  clickMe() {
    console.log(document.querySelector('a'));
    document.querySelector('a')?.focus();
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xiatkh?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fkarma.conf.js)

Comment: that gave me a good clue to the actual solution, thank you! some user agents behave differently on :focus-visible, so adding a style to it AND :focus did the trick for me, thanks a lot (also note that solid worked, but 'auto' not)